# How do I auto generate documentation of Yii based web application

Tags: javascript, php, yii, documentation, comments

I have been developing a web app on Yii framework which has around 60% of the codes in javascript. During the development I could not create a simultaneous document of the functionality/code etc., but it just has unstructured comments written alongside the code.

I would like to auto-generate a documentation of my web app in HTML document that displays the comments intermingled with code.

- I tried the yiidocumentor but the output is more of a documentation of Yii itself and it is not documenting javascript functions
- [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.io/docco/) was seemingly the best solution but it is for nodejs based application and I tried using the port of Docco in php ([sourceMakeup](https://github.com/FrediBach/sourceMakeup)) but it is showing no results without showing any error.
  Also, in order to use sourceMakeup I had to move the files outside the Yii framework as I was not able to get it work within Yii framework.

If anyone can provide some direction on auto-generating documentation from source-code and comments that would be of great help.

Big thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) because it is simple, efficient and supports many languages. All that is required is a very minimal structure in comments i.e.

```
/*
 Function: Multiply

 Multiplies two integers.

 Parameters:

  x - The first integer.
  y - The second integer.

 Returns:

  The two integers multiplied together.

 See Also:

  <Divide>
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/).phpDocumentor is a tool with which it is possible to generate documentation from your PHP source code.